# Postfix SMTP-AUTH

Tags: postfix, smtp, openssl, sasl, tls

On a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 server, I have install and configure postfix.

For the SMTP-AUTH I used the **mail-stack-delivery package** (previously packaged as dovecot-postfix).

> sudo apt-get install mail-stack-delivery

After that in /etc/postfix/main.cf I have these two lines:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt

smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

My question is these files **server.crt** and **server.key** are ok OR I have to create others with the openssl (a Self-Signed Certificate).

Comment: Hmm... There's a SnakeOil cert/key that should not be used. I'm not sure about `/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt`. Do you even have that cert/key (or is it a place holder)? Can you post `/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt` with your question? Or perhaps its thumbprint with `openssl x509 -fingerprint -in /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is dependent. In some cases can you do just fine with the generated ones.
But the best practice and my strongest advice is to generate new ones. That because some clients or servers might reject to deliver when the `common name` or domain tag on your server certificates doesn't match the destination they are trying to deliver to. Also if you have clients with the right version of outlook, will they be nagged with a warning they can't get rid off unless you create a correct certificate and install the public part or CA on the client.